# Branching and merging Biztalk orchestrations and maps

Tags: biztalk, branching-and-merging

If making changes to a Biztalk orchestration (.odx) or map (.btm) in two branches, e.g. in tfs or git, is there robust and well-defined way of merging the changes from one branch to the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no good way to really merge or diff ODX and BTM files.  BTM files in particular get rough because they tend to be stored on a single line.  ODX files contain plenty of GUIDs that change, as well as designer information that's difficult to merge.  This generally means that if there are differences I end up taking server or keeping local and working with the other developer to make changes.

Your best strategy is probably to put code that will change into a helper library and to call it from expression shapes and/or ExternalAssembly scripting functoids. Source control will work well for branching/merging changes to a .NET library.

Obviously this won't be able to capture all differences.  You should also try to modularize Orchestrations when possible (use call/start orchestration, partner correlation, etc.) so that the individual artifacts are small and won't require (as?) many concurrent changes.

One other possibility for maps is to have them refer to external XSLT that is source controlled - but then you lose the value of the mapper designer.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! You confirmed my suspicions.